# Reorder a list of String into a new list

Tags: vb.net

I want to reorder a list of strings into a different list of strings. I am creating multiple loops to do this, however i was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

```
        Dim values As New List(Of String)

    For Each val As String In vals

        If val.Contains("10") And val.Contains("Year 1") Then

            values.Add(val)

        End If

    Next

    For Each val As String In vals

        If val.Contains("20") And val.Contains("Year 1") Then

            values.Add(val)

        End If

    Next
```

There are going to be quite a lot of these loops to do what I want can anyone offer any help or a better way to go about doing this? Note that I want the values list to return 10,10,10,20,20,20 so that lines that have 10 should be added first and lines with 20 then afterwards.

thanks,

Stefan

Comment: Homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: Is this somehow separated like a CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be ordered by the year, this will work:

```
Dim result = (From item In values
      Where item.ToLower Like "*year #*"
      Let year = Regex.Match(item.Substring(item.ToLower.IndexOf("year ")), "\d+").Value
      Order By year).ToList()
```

But you've said that you want it to be ordered by 10,20,30 and so on. But i don't see how this should work.

1. The value could be 8,25,4711 instead and how do want to find it at all in the String?
2. `Contains` only checks whether the line contains this substring or not, but you might have this number also in the year part(f.e. year 10) or elsewhere.

So your requirement looks very error-prone and vague.

**Edit**: If the text is so strict as in your comment's samples, you could simplify it to this, splitting each line into tokens separated by comma:

```
Dim result = (From item In values
          Let Tokens = item.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          Let Count = Int32.Parse(Tokens(3))
          Let Year = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(Tokens(5), "\d+").Value)
          Order By Count, Year
          Select item).ToList()
```

Comment: COM317,Introduction to databases,2,20,M,Year 1, the 20 value in the string and the year is what i want the new list ordered by so this
COM317,Introduction to databases,2,10,M,Year 1
COM317,Introduction to databases,2,10,M,Year 1
COM317,Introduction to databases,2,20,M,Year 1
COM317,Introduction to databases,2,20,M,Year 1
you can see that the 10's in year 1 are added in first

Comment: @StefanReaney: Edited my answer to provide an even more simplified version which works with your provided sample data. If the data is not so strict, you might get an idea anyway.

Comment: ah i see what that code is doing, its getting there, unfortunately i need to to this for multiple years so i want COM317,Introduction to databases,2,10,M,Year 1.. COM317,Introduction to databases,2,20,M,Year 1 and COM317,Introduction to databases,2,10,M,Year 2 and COM317,Introduction to databases,2,20,M,Year 2 is it an easy tweak to do so?

Comment: @StefanReaney: That code works already for multiple years(and orders by count and then years). But mind that it wouldn't work anymore if some of the parts would also contain commas(f.e. `Introduction to databases,C#`) because i'm getting them by index. Do you need to order by year and then count? Then you just have to swap the order in the query.

Comment: note what is this method used, (from...) what type of query is this

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim values As List(Of String) = vals.OrderBy(Function(s)
         If s.Contains("Year 1") Then
             If s.Contains("10") Then Return 0
             If s.Contains("20") Then Return 1
         End If
         Return Integer.MaxValue
    End Function).ToList()
```

It sounds like you may also want to create a regular expression for this string, to pull out the fields you care about. That should make this perform a lot better. To help you with the correct expression we'll need to know a lot more about what the strings look like.

Comment: what is happening in the above code? sorry this is quite new, the string type is COM133,Introduction to databases,1,10.. <--- like this